# How can I prevent sizeToFit from changing the UILabel width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, width, uilabel

I have a UILabel right now and the UILabel.text value changes regularly.

The problem I am having is that if each time the UILabel.text value changes, the UILabel width changes according to the content of the label.

How can I fix this? This is my code I have right now:

```
outputLabel.text = errorMessage;
outputLabel.hidden = NO;
[outputLabel sizeToFit];
```

**UPDATE**
The reason I am using sizeToFit is because I need the height to automatically change.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: If you don't want the label resized, don't call `sizeToFit`. The whole point of that method is to resize the label to just fit the text it contains.

Comment: But I want the height to be changed.

Comment: Then calculate the size of the new text based on a fixed width. Then set the label's frame to match the calculated height and the given width.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: There are various methods for `NSString` (in a `UIKit` category) that perform the calculations. Do some searching on how to determine the size of a string.

Comment: @maddy no kidding, wow!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create a category or a subclass of UILabel and add this method to resize only the height of the label depending to the input text

```
- (void)heightToFit {

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

    CGRect labelRect = self.frame;
    labelRect.size.height = textSize.height;
    [self setFrame:labelRect];
}
```

and use it instead sizeToFit

Comment: This is going to sound daft. How would I create a subclass of the UILabel,  I have seen people talk about that, but I have never found out how to do it

Comment: is deprecated since iOS7 , now the new method to use is 'sizeWithAttributes:' so you need to implement at rutime to use iOS6 and before method or iOS7 method. Another good reason to create a subclass or a category with the method to resize the label

Comment: I am not developing the app for iOS 6

Comment: so you need just to replace the deprecated method with the new method

Comment: @Manu - FYI - if you have an app with a deployment target of iOS 6 or earlier and a Base SDK of iOS 7, you can safely use `sizeWithFont...` with iOS 7 and earlier. Deprecated methods can be used without issue (other than a possible warning). If you only support iOS 7, then you should use the new method.

Comment: Ok, so you support iOS6, then you can use the deprecated method, but is not the bet thing to do. The correct implementation should be select at runtime the correct method depending to the iOS version of the hardware is running the app

Answer (score 2):

Use `[UILabel sizeThatFits:]` with a `CGSize` with infinite height like `(320, 10000)`.

Comment: The method returns a `CGSize` (it doesn't change the `UILabel`), you need to extract the height from that `CGSize` and assign it to the `UILabel`.

Comment: Last I checked 10000 was not infinite. ;) Use `HUGE_VALF`.

Comment: @chaiguy thx for that, just too lazy to check what the actual const name is :) Anyway if one has a 10000px height view, there are other things he should be more worried about.

Comment: When dealing with CGFloat values, always use CGFLOAT_MAX or CGFLOAT_MIN.  Don't depend on them always being doubles.

Answer (score 2):

I subclassed UILabel and overrode the sizeThatFits method to look like this:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize res = [super sizeThatFits:size];

    return CGSizeMake(size.width, res.height);
}
```

Then if I add the label into a nib I place a UILabel from the object library.  After that I make sure to set the class of the placed label to my custom class instead of the default of UILabel.

It basically just overrides the new width with the original width so it never changes width, but dynamically changes height.

Answer (score 0):

Use following trick to do the job done:

First is set tag of uiLabel. My cell.yourLable tag is 998

```
cell.yourLable.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.yourLable sizeToFit];

UILabel *myLbl=[cell.contentView viewWithTag:998];
CGRect frm=cell.yourLable.frame;
frm.size.width = cell.contentView.frame.size.width;
myLbl.frame=frm;
```

Here the trick is to get same UiLabel by tag and set its width by setting frame.